# jQuery - change image on click for many div's

Tags: jquery, image, click

i have many div's with the same background image and i want change this background when I click the one of them.

I'm training with some like this:

**body**:

```
<div id="basket-plusminus"></div>
...
<div id="basket-plusminus"></div>

<script>
$("#basket-plusminus").toggle(
function () {
$(this).addClass("click-plusminus");
},
function () {
$(this).removeClass("click-plusminus");
}
);
</script>
```

in css:

```
#basket-plusminus {
width:11px;
height:11px;
background:url(../img/icons/plus-min.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
cursor:pointer;
}

.click-plusminus {
background-image:url(../img/icons/minus-min.png) !important;
}
```

**i don't know how add the auto id's in that, mayby this is a sollution.**

help

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same `id`, this is invalid. An `id` ***must*** be unique in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a little rework of your markup and javascript you could do this: http://jsfiddle.net/Wrxdy/ of course keep the backgrounds you have - I'm just toggling colors for example.

Answer (score 0):

Use class istead of the id tag since ids are unique.

Try:

```
<div class="basket-plusminus"></div>
...
<div class="basket-plusminus"></div>

<script>
$(".basket-plusminus").toggle(
    function ()
    {
        $(this).addClass("click-plusminus");
    },
    function ()
    {
        $(this).removeClass("click-plusminus");
    }
);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you fix the same ID problem, this code line should be helpful for you

$.(document).ready(function()
{

$("#backet-plusminus").click(function() { $('myOjbect').css('background-image', 'url(' + imageUrl + ')'); });

})